# Illustrator: How to prevent layers showing white background?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, layers, background, creative-cloud

Just installed Illustrator CC. Coming from PS, I would really like to see a 'transparent' background in my layers. In PS, you see a checkered background when no pixels are present in the canvas -- would love the same in Illustrator but it defaults to white and I can't seem to figure out how to disable it. Help appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

from the menu, select `View / Show Transparency Grid`

or hit <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>